# Why when I create a template in the DocUSign UI do I have to specify a recipient?

Tags: docusignapi

Why when I create a template in the DocUSign UI do I have to specify a recipient - I don't know who will be the recipient yet?

As you can see from the below picture, when I create a template I have to specify a recipient but at this stage I do not know who the recipient will be.

Below is my request data. Here I am hardcoding that Bill Doe will be the recipient and providing his email. In production this name and email will be passed to me as a variable. I won't know the values of name and email beforehand so how can I provide this in the UI?

```
const requestData: RequestData = {
    templateId,
    templateRoles: [
      {
        email: "billdoe@protonmail.com",
        name: "Bill Doe",
        roleName: "signer",
        tabs: {
          signHereTabs: [
            {
              anchorString: "/XSIGNHEREX/",
              anchorUnits: "pixels",
              anchorXOffset: "20",
              anchorYOffset: "10",
              tabLabel: "signHere",
            },
          ],
          textTabs: [
            {
              anchorString: "/LegalRenewalPrice/",
              anchorUnits: "pixels",
              anchorXOffset: "20",
              anchorYOffset: "10",
              tabLabel: "renewalPrice",
              width: "100",
              value: renewalPrice,
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    ],
    status: "sent",
  };
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to, it's optional.
You can just give it a role, and not fill the name and email.
These are two types of recipients - placeholder is what you want.

As longs the role you specified in the UI matches the `roleName` you give it in the JSON you had - it will work.

Comment: Thanks. It wasn't obvious to me that you didn't have to provide a name or email within the UI. I've changed the role to "placeholder" and referenced it in the JSON  roleName: "placeholder". Now when I do the flow my text tabs or sign tab does not appear within the receipient view url?

Comment: That's a different/new issue. It's possible that the anchor strings you specified are not found on the document. Also, you can have the tabs in the template itself, not in the code. That depends on your situation. Will the tabs change each time you use the template?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a template using the DocuSign app (or via the API), you need to create at least one recipient -- either a `role` (where you don't know the name/email/sms yet) or a "hardcoded" recipient where you set the name, email.

Are you creating a template via the API? That's not a usual use case. Much more commonly: create the template using the DocuSign app, then reference the template when you send the envelope.

Here's a [live example](https://codepen.io/docusign/full/MWXPKJY) that will upload a template to your account, then use it in an envelope.

Here's the envelope request that references the template. The signer data is dynamic:

See line 80 of the CodePen JavaScript

```
        const req = {
            status: "sent",
            compositeTemplates: [
                {
                    compositeTemplateId: "1",
                    serverTemplates: [
                        {
                            sequence: "1",
                            templateId: templates[0].templateId
                        }
                    ],
                    inlineTemplates: [
                        {
                            sequence: "1",
                            customFields: { // optional metadata
                                listCustomFields: [ 
                                    {
                                        name: "Envelope list custom field 1",
                                        show: "true",
                                        value: "value 5"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            recipients: {
                                signers: [
                                    {
                                        email: email,
                                        name: name,
                                        clientUserId: clientUserId, // embedded signing
                                        roleName: "Signer1",
                                        recipientId: "1",
                                        customFields: [ // optional metadata
                                            "field1: value 1",
                                            "field2: value 2"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        };
```